# Get the position of div on page scroll in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm stuck at the point to fix the position of the my menu div that is in the center of the page or sometime on the top that depends on the content. i wanna to fix the position of the div when i scroll the page so that It display in the top of the page(even it is in center or top or bottom).Please let me know how can i get the position of the div and apply the css position fixed when it reach on  the top of the page using the jquery. for example http://new.livestream.com/live-video-tools

Comment: Hello, take a look at http://www.sutanaryan.com/jquery/how-to-create-fixed-menu-when-scrolling-page-with-css-and-jquery/

Comment: Ihave checked it, it is using the static height 136 from the top, I wanna height dynamic not sure about the position of the menu because it depending on the content

Answer (score 1):

I made a try : [see JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dyrJ/)

Thing is to change the css attribute of the containers that need to be fixed once scroll reach it :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var iMenuTop = $('.menu').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var iWinTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(iWinTop >= iMenuTop)
            $('.menu').css({
                position:'fixed',
                top:0});
        else
            $('.menu').css('position','static');         
    });
});
```

Working with Firefox, not sur for the others...

Edit : it's really a draft, you might have to adapt e.g. if with there is already a scroll when loading, which can occur by using browser back button.